# Alternatives to using the clipboard feature in Automation Anywhere

Tags: automation, automationanywhere

What are some alternatives to using the clipboard feature in Automation Anywhere? I'm told using the clipboard feature is not ideal for consistency.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What are you trying to do with the clipboard?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable instead of using clipboard.
Steps to create variable:

1. Select the variable manager from the extreme right side of workbench window
2. click on Add at the bottom of variable manager section
3. In Add Variable window, provide the details of the variable which needs to be created

You can refer [How to create variables in Automation Anywhere Client](https://youtu.be/TzVscDac_7o?list=PLkkGqdBS1r08Fd6meBZ7zHJXA15Q5Up2w&t=724)

Answer (score 0):

That is True. Even if user is not using the system while AA bot is running, some background services might kick in and use clipboard(only id programmer have used it)

Note: Sometimes, depending on situation. Like a secure excel files where if we need to copy data between workbooks/sheets, we are stuck with `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V`

Alternatives go as below:
1. For values, use variables instead of clipboard
2. Excel files, use `Get Cell` and `Set Cell` also consider connecting to Excel as database
3. File Copy, use the `Copy File` option

I cannot think of anymore scenarios as of now, but let me know what exactly were you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'Prompt-Assignment' variable for holding temporary values. Use of 'Clipboard' should only be done where a Ctrl+C action needs to be performed however the value should immediately be transferred in 'Prompt-Assignment' or any other variable for holding the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other system variables according to the application you are using

For ex:
        Excel : Excel Column
        CSV/TXT : FileData Column

These system variable  will hold the values inside the loop only. you can assign in to some other custom variable and you can use it anywhere.